# iOS UI snapshot testing how to have different Reference Images folder for multiple targets

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xctestcase, snapshot-testing

I have a project with 4 targets, since it's a whitelabel app, basically most of the code is common, except the branding (images, colors etc).

I'm trying to set up UI Snapshots tests for each, but I want to avoid having duplicated code as well, so I don't want to have 4 different UI Test targets per brand, with 4 different UI folders.

I did find an option online based on this article: https://medium.com/@rijalab/how-to-use-one-test-target-files-for-two-app-targets-in-ios-37df53265a5

Which involved creating separated tests targets indeed, but keeping still one folder for your Test Cases only, in which you add a switch between the targets, as per example:

```
#if Brand1Test
@testable import Brand1
#elseif Brand2Test
@testable import Brands2
.
.
and so on
#endif
```

This works in the case of Unit tests, sure, but in the case of UI Snapshot tests, the shapshots will always go in the same folder ->> therefore, they will always fail cause they don't match when you switch brands.

My question is:

- How/Where can I override this path, and eventually inside the ReferenceImage snapshot folder to have a separation of the brands first, so ... UITests/ReferenceImages/Brand1/ButtonSnapshot etc.
- Is there a better solution except the one I found?